# installed jdk by and have Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: 12.04, jdk

I am getting my new laptop going and went to install the latest oracle JDK 7u25. I followed the instructions on [this site](http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-update-25-on-ubuntu-12-04-linux/) to do it.

Afterwards when I type `java --version` in the terminal I get the error:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
```

I tried reinstalling it via a different method but the error wont go away. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Answer (score 115):

Use:

```
java -version
```

instead of:

```
java --version
```

However, it's still not excusable that such cryptic error message is produced for the extra dash sign. Especially because java is not an amateur software but a kind of the very best software.

Comment: @Umair Thus, the upvote...

Comment: Wonder how many pro devs have been brought to their knees by this one. Thanks!!

Comment: @Dmitriy Sintsov: Just goes a long way towards telling that it is far from the very best software. Just because it is popular, doesn't mean it's good - otherwise JavaScript would be the most awesome language in the world - it isn't ...

Comment: I literally just got the same "cryptic" error when just using `java -v`